# cat leaves UTF-8 BOM alone

Tags: cat, unicode

`cat` is the command to concatenate files, however it seems it doesn't work with UTF-8 files with BOM (byte order mark).

Those files have some bytes at the beginning which define the byte order (big / little endian). They are invisible in text editors like `vi`.

If I concatenate such files, I don't expect to have the BOM multiple times in the concatenation result. Unfortunately `cat` doesn't care about that. It took me hours to find the problem, because I didn't knew my files have BOMs and Notepad++ doesn't even show them if they are in the middle of the file.

So my question is: How can I concatenate multiple UTF-8 files with BOM? At the moment I'm trying to remove the BOM with `sed` and then add it again to the resulting file, but it still doesn't work and I wondered if there is a more simple solution or if I didn't use `cat` correctly.

Comment: The correct way is to not use BOMs in UTF-8.

Comment: It is not the job of `cat` to remove a BOM from the second and subsequent files that you are concatenating together.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/292086/38062 seems appropriate here.